# Question about the construction of lebesgue measure of $(0,1]$ (or: the Borel sigma algebra is generated by the half open intervals)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am reading the book "Probability with Martingales"

In this book, the author constructs lebesgue measure on (0,1] as follows.

Let $F =$ the collection of subsets of $(0,1]$ which can be written as a finite union of $(a_i,b_i]$

Then, he claims that the $B((0,1]) = $ the sigma algebra generated by $F$.

What makes me confused is that:

Isn't $B((0,1])$ the sigma algebra generated by the open subsets of $(0,1]$?

Then, why is it that any open set of $(0,1]$ is a member of the sigma algebra generated by F?
How do I know this?

Conversely, why is it that an element of the sigma algebra generated by $F$, such as $(0,1/2]$ is a member of $B((0,1])$?

Any clarification please?

Comment: What is the definition of $B((0,1])$ -- is it the borel sets? If so maybe the author is saying that the borel sets can also be regarded as the sigma algebra generated by $F$, which seems it would be not hard to show.

Comment: I allowed myself to change the title of your question, to make it easier to find in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you know that each open interval is contained in $B((0,1])$. Hence, so is

$$
(a, b] = \bigcap_n \left(a, b + \frac{1}{n} \right).
$$

Conversely, note that each open interval

$$
(a,b) = \bigcup_n \left(a, b-\frac{1}{n} \right]
$$

is contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the half open intervals.

Finally, you should check that every (nonempty) open subset of $(0,1])$ is a countable (or finite) union of open intervals, so that

$$
U = \bigcup_n (a_n, b_n)
$$

is also contained in the $\sigma$ algebra generated by the half open intervals, because (as seen above) it already contains all open intervals.

All in all, we have shown that the set of half open intervals is an (alternative) **generating system** for the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra, just as the class of open sets is.